# Is it a bad practice if we position breadcrumb to the right side of page header?

Tags: breadcrumbs, ux-designer, lean-ux

Our website is a marketing based site. We don’t have more than 4 levels in breadcrumb and have lots of space in the right side of the website.

Is there any issue if we put the breadcrumb on the right side?

Comment: Can you show us a design?

Answer (score 1):

Putting it on the right side will make it **not very obvious** for your user. User are used to see breadcrum on the top or left. (Designed like this because of the *`F` reading user theory*).

I think top is the *best practice* but if you don't have space and without having more graphic contents from your website, I have to leave you judge.

According to what you asked : you can move your main content to the right and put the breadcrum **on the left** on this content like in Windows.

[image: DocOrdered]

Answer (score 1):

Although I have no idea about the design/layout of your website, but the position of breadcrumbs is relative to content. Its about alignment.

There is nothing wrong in keeping the breadcrumbs on right if the content is right aligned. And since it forms a **secondary navigation** for your site, If you are thinking to fill up the space on right side, I think you should re-think.

Imagine a scenario. To back track, your user will look on the right side! Not done! They wont like the idea!

You will be able to refer to [examples of bread crumbs in this article along with the practices](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/03/17/breadcrumbs-in-web-design-examples-and-best-practices/)

And some more examples are [complied in this article along with best practices](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/breadcrumb-navigation-examined-best-practices-examples/)

Comment: If the language is RTL then the user might look to the right!

Comment: Exactly. And that is one important thing ....it is relative to the content language. :)

Answer (score 1):

Most breadcrumbs are on the left of the page because it's simply not possible to know exactly how far it will extend to the right as the user moves through the site.

Because this layout is so common, most users will expect to be able to find the breadcrumb trail on the left of the page.

It is, of course, possible to place it anywhere you wish provided that you know you have room for it - The one caveat being that, if you are going to place it in the right side of the page, it should always extend to the right:

```
level 1 >
level 1 > level 2 >
level 1 > level 2 > level 3 >
```

and not extend left-wards:

```
                    level 1 >
          level 1 > level 2 >
level 1 > level 2 > level 3 >
```

to prevent the user from becoming confused with which link they want to click on

Answer (score 0):

No, so long as it goes vertically down. Meaning, step by step, if you glance at the right it shows from top down which step you're on, and that as you scroll down (if necessary) it scrolls with you. Further, if it's one form, you can have the right side breadcrumb dynamically highlight which step you're now on.

Answer (score 0):

According to this hypothesis of mine: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/2056/any-research-on-right-hand-left-hand-based-preferences-when-interacting-with-an, it should remain on the left, being a navigation element.